# Django: dynamic form generation (changing field type)

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a **model** wich defines certain field`s types

```
class FieldType(models.Model): #determines types of fields which are availiable to choose
EMAIL = 'E'
INTEGER = 'I'
STRING = 'S'
TEXT = 'T'
FIELD_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    (EMAIL, 'E-mail'),
    (INTEGER, 'Integer'),
    (STRING, 'String'),
    (TEXT, 'Text'),
)
type_of_field = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                                  choices=FIELD_TYPE_CHOICES,
                                  default=STRING)

def is_upperclass(self):
    return self.type_of_field in (self.EMAIL, self.TEXT)
```

So this is a field with type`s choices.

I also have a class in **model.py** which let user add new field:

```
class ColumnHead(models.Model):
    newfield = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='head')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.newfield)

class ExtraField(models.Model):
    add = models.ForeignKey(ColumnHead)
    new_field_text = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='content')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.new_field_text)

class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ExtraField
    extra = 1 # how many extra choices it could be

class AdminForm(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Head', {'fields': ['newfield']}),
        ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
```

**The concept is to make a new field have that chosen type.**

So, what is only to do is to create a function (I guess) which defines the behavior of the additional field. But because of my poor Django and Python knowlege I do not have any confidence. I don`t know how to write it an where (views or forms or models?). I thought I need something like this class in forms:

```
class DynamicType(forms.Form):
    if field.type == 'E':
       and there must be some action...
    elif field.type == 'I':
       ...
```

I really searched a lot, but I could not find anything like this. Or, maybe, this way I`m doing is completely wrong? Please, help.

**EDIT:**

I`ve made some changes here in model (replaced class ExtraField and added three potentional types):

```
class ExtraTextField(models.Model):
    add = models.ForeignKey(ColumnHead)
    new_field_text = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name='content')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.new_field_text)

class ExtraIntegerField(models.Model):
    add = models.ForeignKey(ColumnHead)
    new_field_integer = models.IntegerField(max_length=200, verbose_name='content')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.new_field_integer)

class ExtraDateField(models.Model):
    add = models.ForeignKey(ColumnHead)
    new_field_date = models.DateField(max_length=200, verbose_name='content')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.new_field_date)
```

Class ChoiceInline manages field types. I need a function which says something like: if it was chosen "Integer", lets use `ExtraIntegerField`, am I right? Maybe I should not worry about forms... and I need a function here in models directly?

**BIG** thanks for ANY idea or help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, there's almost always a better idea than dynamic model fields.
However **maybe** this app will help you or at least give you direction:

https://github.com/dobarkod/django-dynamic-model

Comment: You were right, saying that there are another ways. Don`t know why I didn`t think of it earlier... It`s called "to get caught in an endless loop". I`ve made another solution: just added necessary classes for field types like ExtraTextField, ExtraURLField an so on, made for each of them classes AddText, AddURL (with the same content as ChoiceInline but with necessary parameters) and edited class AdminForm. So simple. I really need more experience. Anyway, thank you for your help!